# casperjs: how to capture page in loop with ajax update

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I have a page that updates via ajax (so no page load) via a 'next' button.  I'd like to click the 'next' button (an onclick js function) and grab the page source each time and repeat this N number of times.

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var limit = 10, count = 0;

casper.start('http://example.com');

casper.then(function() {

casper.repeat(limit, function() {

    this.echo(this.getHTML());
    this.echo('-------------------------');
    this.click('.next-btn');
    wait(2000);
    count++;

});

});

casper.run();
```

This captures the source, but keeps getting the same source, not the updated markup from clicking the 'next' button.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong, you have a mis-used `wait(2000)`. The wait does no stop the execution. The next line `count++` and the loop continues.

In short, wait is asynchronous and if you need actually wait for sometime and then execute a block of code, use the wait callback function as shown in the documentation:

```
casper.start('http://yoursite.tld/');

casper.wait(1000, function() {
    this.echo("I've waited for a second.");
});

casper.run();
```

Had you've done the below code, you would not get the desired result:

```
casper.start('http://yoursite.tld/');

casper.wait(1000);
this.echo("I've waited for a second.");

casper.run();
```

Thus, you need to chain it: Let me try modifying your code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var limit = 10, count = 0, waitms = 2000;

casper.start('http://example.com');

casper.then(function() {
    // Raise a custom event (for the first load)
    casper.emit("ajax.content.loaded");

    // Event listener for a custom event
    casper.on("ajax.content.loaded", function () {

        // Increase counter
        count++;
        // Break loop when limit is reached
        if(c > limit) {
            casper.exit();
        }

        this.echo(this.getHTML());
        this.echo('-------------------------');
        this.click('.next-btn');

        casper.wait(waitms, function () {
            // Recursively raise the custom event after waiting a bit
            casper.emit("ajax.content.loaded");
        });

    });

});

casper.run();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Without the page provided, I can't quite test it, but I think your problem is that CasperJS  does exactly what Google Chrome does - it simply returning the source that was initially served from the server.

Take this site for example: http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-11/app/#/phones

This is Google's tutorial for AngularJS. When you view the source, all it contains is:

```
<body>
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

But in the JavaScript console, running

```js
document.body.innerHTML;
```

Returns the generated HTML that's on the page at that time.

For CasperJS, you probably want to take a look at [`evaluate()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate) and run the above JavaScript to get the updated HTML.

Comment: Thank you VERY much for your help Trevor.  Yeah I'm still trying to get my head around the abstraction between casperjs and the webpage.  I understand that evaluate() means to run something on the page, but why can't I run document.body.innerHTML outside of an evaluate()?  Does casper have no knowledge of the actual webpage?  If so, then why does click() work outside of an evaluate()?  BTW the webpage I'm trying to get the full source of is:  http://lozo.com/grocery-coupons-bundler

Comment: The click function is actually a wrapper around evaluate under the hood with some extra functionality. If it fails to click the element in JavaScript (e.g. evaluate), it will try using native QtWebkitEvents to perform the click ([doc](http://goo.gl/7d5NAe)). There is [text in the documentation](http://goo.gl/BkljJZ) that tries to explain how evaluate works. I agree that it's a little hard to wrap your head around at first. Think of CasperJS as the high level thing that controls the browser, and evaluate() as a way to run some native JS in that browser (as you would in the JS console).